# Creating Dnf and Cnf in Python out of a logictable (sympy, sagemath)

Tags: python, sympy, logical-operators, sage

I am currently in developement of tasks in OpenEDX if anyone knows it.
I want to create logictables and let others evaluate the dnf and cnf out of the logictable.
I started working with sympy but it evaluates just one answer, so I found out about sagemath which also has a logic libary.
So I tryed it out, but I am not sure how to create a logictable manually and get the dnf out of it. In the documentation you can just get the truthtable out of a logic function or am I missing something?

```
s = propcalc.formula("z1")
s.truthtable()
```

I was hoping that I can generate a truthtable manually with something like this

```
t = logictable.truthtable(values, variables)
```

and get the dnf out of it.

Comment: I'm sure this can be done with sympy but I don't really understand what you want as input and output

Comment: The users input a string, where which I convert so it matches a sympy dnf. But if I compare 2 strings the user needs to input the variables in a specific order or I need to somehow split the string into the variables and compare them.
Or does sympy have a "compare dnfs" with each other function, so I can cast the string to a dnf and I get True when z1+z2 == z2+z1 for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a truth table, use the `sympy.satisfiable` function, listing all
the symbol assignments that make the logic expression be true.

Using this truth table, the `sympy.POSform` and `sympy.SOPform` functions
will provide the smallest POS or SOP logic expression.

Also, note that `sympy.sympify` uses `eval`, so make sure the string expression
is sanitized.

```
from sympy import *

my_names = 'ABCD'
A,B,C,D = symbols(','.join(my_names))
ns1 = {'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C, 'D': D}
my_symbols = tuple(ns1.values())
es1 = '~(C | D | ~(A | B))'
e1 = sympify(es1, locals=ns1)
print(f"String {es1} with symbols {my_symbols}",
      f"\n\tmakes expression {e1}")
models = satisfiable(e1, all_models=True)
minterms = list(models)
print('SOP form (DNF):', SOPform(my_symbols, minterms))
print('POS form (CNF):', POSform(my_symbols, minterms))
```

Output:

```
# String ~(C | D | ~(A | B)) with symbols (A, B, C, D)
#   makes expression ~(C | D | ~(A | B))
# SOP form (DNF): (A & ~C & ~D) | (B & ~C & ~D)
# POS form (CNF): ~C & ~D & (A | B)
```